# html css background-image

Tags: html, css

What's wrong with this code?
It doesn't show me anything on the screen:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <head>
    <title> CSS(lab2) </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <style type = "text/css">
        .bg {
         background-image: url("charlesb.jpg");
         background-color: green;
       }
      </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div class= "bg">

    </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: set width and height for `div.bg` (or fill it by text for test) and check the path to image.

Comment: Probably because your `<div>` is empty and therefore has no height and width. Set it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <head>
    <title> CSS(lab2) </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <style type = "text/css">
        .bg {
         background-image: url("charlesb.jpg");
         background-color: green;
       }
      </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div class= "bg">
It needs something inside the div
    </div>
 </body>
```

You must have content inside the `div` to have the background color/image show.

Comment: This is not necessarily true. Your `div` needs to have dimensions, which are 0,0 by default when the div is empty, but you could just give the div dimensions without giving the div content.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the size of your background image (e.g. 300x200) you can do this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <head>
    <title> CSS(lab2) </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <style type = "text/css">
        .bg {
         background-image: url("charlesb.jpg");
         background-color: green;
         width: 300px;
         height: 200px;
       }
      </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div class= "bg">

    </div>
 </body>
```

Simply add *width* and *height* statements into your css style.